# Nexus OSS does not start

Tags: nexus, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I'm trying to install nexus 3.38 on a debian 10 system. I use aodoptopenjdk-8... as Java runtime.

When I try running it as a systemd sevrice nexus does not start. There are no usable logs.

Whe I try running nexus directly with command `nexus start-launchd` (virtually the same as `nexus start`) I get the following out put

```
bin/nexus start-launchd
Starting nexus
Could not resolve mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/6.0.5
```

I look for this library/dependency and find it in `{nexus-home}/system/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.framework/6.0.5/`. But the filename looks crippled `org.apache.felix.framework-` that's it. No `*.jar`. The same can be seen with some other dependencies, like other felix stuff or karaf.

Other dependecies in `{nexus-home}/system` look fine.

If I change the name from `org.apache.felix.framework-` to `org.apache.felix.framework-6.0.5.jar` then it looks like this dependency loaded and next stop is karaf.

Do I have to fix all the names of the jar files? Why do I not find other complains about that, is it an error in front of my monitor?

I've seen the same problem with current release of apache karaf. The names of the jar files are crippled.

Comment: I see that this problem exists only in the unix version of the nexus package (*.tar.gz) the windows package (*.zip) looks ok at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the folder `system` of the unix package (*.tar.gz) of nexus 3.38.0-01 is damaged.

I've downloaded the windows package (*.zip) and replaced the `system` with this version.

Everything looks fine now.